# my app crashes on iOS 16.4 with No such process

Tags: ios, flutter, crash

My flutter app crashes iOS 16.4 and below, but it works fine on iOS 17
on VScode.

It doesn't show any error message, so I tried running it on Xcode, it shows this message.

Also I tried a real device, still crashes, anyone has any idea about what is happening?

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-23 15:57:22 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
Application launch for 'com.___.eg' did not return a process handle nor launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 1728;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A344)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-10-23T18:57:22+03:00
```

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm getting this same message. Rosetta is installed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, installing rosetta helped me:

softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license

Comment: still not fixing it